# Removing the effect of color table, after the table ends

Tags: tables, color, cases

I am using color tables in my document, as it produces very nice results.
Further to that I use some equations using cases environment. I see that the 
colors from the color table get mixed up with the equations.

How to remove the effect of color table once I finished using it in a table.
Here is a MWE to reproduce the problem. If I un-comment the line `\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}`, I see that the half brace goes missing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,rgb,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$TxCost_p$} \\\hhline{~---}
        \multirow{-2}{*}{p} & min   & max    & avg   \\\hline\hline
        1 & 1.13  & 14.00  & 2.57  \\\hline
        2 & 1.78  & 29.98  & 4.13  \\\hline
        4 & 3.97  & 47.23  & 11.07 \\\hline
        8 & 5.43  & 87.86  & 18.82\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{performance }
\end{table}
%\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}


\begin{equation}
    Time = \begin{cases}
        m \cdot C + 2 T & \mbox{in the computation }\\ 
        (m+1) \cdot T & \mbox{in the transfer }
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

and here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I am pretty sure, that `\rowcolors` command must be within `\begin{table}...\end{table}`, not outside

Comment: @ChristianHupfer got the mistake !  I think I copied from the wrong example. thanks.

Comment: You may consider to accept the answer by user LaRiFari below too, to `close` this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command `\rowcolors{}{}{}` has to be situated inside your `table` environment.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table,rgb,hyperref]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \hline
        & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$TxCost_p$} \\\hhline{~---}
        \multirow{-2}{*}{p} & min   & max    & avg   \\\hline\hline
        1 & 1.13  & 14.00  & 2.57  \\\hline
        2 & 1.78  & 29.98  & 4.13  \\\hline
        4 & 3.97  & 47.23  & 11.07 \\\hline
        8 & 5.43  & 87.86  & 18.82\\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{performance }
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
    Time = \begin{cases}
        m \cdot C + 2 T & \mbox{in the computation }\\ 
        (m+1) \cdot T & \mbox{in the transfer }
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here, how I would have done it:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\rowcolors{2}{white}{gray!25}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cS[table-format=1.2]S[table-format=2.2]S[table-format=2.2]}
\toprule
       \multirow{2}*{$p$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$Tx\text{Cost}_p$} \\\cmidrule(l){2-4}
        & {min}   & {max}    & {avg}   \\
        1 & 1.13  & 14.00  & 2.57  \\
        2 & 1.78  & 29.98  & 4.13  \\
        4 & 3.97  & 47.23  & 11.07 \\
        8 & 5.43  & 87.86  & 18.82\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\caption{performance }
\end{table}

\begin{equation}
    Time = \begin{cases}
        m \cdot C + 2 T & \text{in the computation }\\ 
        (m+1) \cdot T & \text{in the transfer }
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you use it with longtable?